# jooq-3.2.0 and db2 database

Tags: java, sql, db2, jooq

Can I use jooq-3.2.0 to work with db2 database, if yes which driver i have to use while generating entity classes from existing schema. I tried to use org.jooq.util.db2.DB2Database, but generator throws exception. Here is stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jooq.util.db2.DB2Database
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at org.jooq.util.GenerationTool.loadClass(GenerationTool.java:335)
    at org.jooq.util.GenerationTool.run(GenerationTool.java:212)
    at org.jooq.util.GenerationTool.main(GenerationTool.java:141)
    at org.jooq.util.GenerationTool.main(GenerationTool.java:128)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jooq.util.db2.DB2Database
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at org.jooq.util.GenerationTool.loadClass(GenerationTool.java:335)
    at org.jooq.util.GenerationTool.run(GenerationTool.java:212)
    at org.jooq.util.GenerationTool.main(GenerationTool.java:141)
    at org.jooq.util.GenerationTool.main(GenerationTool.java:128)
```

I'm using community edition now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jOOQ 3.2, jOOQ has become [dual-licensed](http://blog.jooq.org/2013/10/09/jooq-3-2-offering-commercial-licensing-and-support/). The DB2 integration is available only with a [jOOQ Enterprise Edition license](http://www.jooq.org/licensing). You may, however, [download a free 30 day trial version](http://www.jooq.org/download/) that works with DB2.

Note, there is also [a fix for jOOQ 3.2.1](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2801) (to be released soon), to give community edition users more information rather than just a stack trace.