# JOOQ with SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, jooq

I am a big fan of ORM especially when it comes to .NET with Entity Framework and using LINQ makes your data access less tedious and more enjoyable.

However, I am working on Java at the moment and particularly looking at ORMs.  I've tried nHybernate against our SQL Server database - and with the absence of keys (unique constraints) on some tables, I've started looking at JOOQ.

I've managed to generate my Java classes from the SQL Server database however - not without error - using JOOQ (v3.2.0).

According to this page [JOOQ Connections](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.1/manual/code-generation/codegen-configuration/) it mentions a class org.jooq.util.sqlserver.SQLServerDatabase.  However when I generated with this in the configuration, I got class not found exception and nothing was generated.  I have had to use org.jooq.util.jdbc.JDBCDatabase to generate my code.

Here is my configuration file (myjooqdbconfig.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.2.0.xsd">
  <jdbc>
    <driver>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver>
    <url>jdbc:sqlserver://MYSERVER:1433;DatabaseName=MYDB</url>
    <user>MYUSER</user>
    <password>PWD</password>
  </jdbc>

  <generator>
    <name>org.jooq.util.DefaultGenerator</name>

    <database>
      <name>org.jooq.util.jdbc.JDBCDatabase</name>

      <inputSchema>dbo</inputSchema>

      <includes>.*</includes>

      <excludes></excludes>
    </database>

    <target>
      <packageName>com.quorum.sentinel.dataAccess</packageName>

      <directory>F:\Libraries\jooq\jOOQ-3.2.0\lib\gen</directory>
    </target>
  </generator>
</configuration>
```

With the class not found exception I had a peek in the JAR file jooq-meta-3.2.0.jar using Java Decompiler where it would appear these classes are located.  I cannot see the org.jooq.util.sqlserver.SQLServerDatabase class definition.

[image: JOOQ Decompile]

I am compiling with:

java -classpath jooq-3.2.0.jar;jooq-meta-3.2.0.jar;jooq-codegen-3.2.0.jar;sqljdbc4.jar;. org.jooq.util.GenerationTool /myjooqdbconfig.xml

Does this org.jooq.util.sqlserver.SQLServerDatabase definition exist in any JAR?

Additionally, having generated the code from the above configuration, it seemed to take a long time and appeared to be in some loop.

Looking in the generated files under dbo - Keys/Tables/Dbo, there were duplicate names of my tables which I noticed when I copied the files into a Netbeans project (lots of errors).  I removed the duplicates and so far so good, I can read various tables from the database in my code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection conn = null;

    String userName = "MYUSER";
    String password = "PWD";
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://MYSERVER:1433;DatabaseName=MYDB";

    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);

        DSLContext create = DSL.using(conn);
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(new Date( new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis())));
        SelectJoinStep<Record> from = create.select().from(Configuration.CONFIGURATION);
        Result<Record> result = from.fetch();
        System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(new Date( new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis())));
        for (Record r : result) {
            Object id =  r.getValue(Configuration.CONFIGURATION.NAME);
            Object time = r.getValue(Configuration.CONFIGURATION.VALUE);
            System.out.println("Record:              : ID: " + id + " Time: " + time);
        }

        System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(new Date( new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis())));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // For the sake of this tutorial, let's keep exception handling simple
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException ignore) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So just to reiterate my questions amongst that mess:

1. Where is the SQL Server specific class org.jooq.util.sqlserver.SQLServerDatabase?
2. Is the above information how you would typically generate SQL Server object mappings?
3. Given that the above almost generated correctly, and that there was duplicate definitions generated in Keys/Tables/Dbo .java files, I don't want to immediately say it is a bug with Jooq - but could be bad database design/incorrect configuration/silly developer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With jOOQ 3.2, jOOQ has become [dual-licensed](http://blog.jooq.org/2013/10/09/jooq-3-2-offering-commercial-licensing-and-support/). The SQL Server integration is available only with a [jOOQ Professional Edition license](http://www.jooq.org/licensing). You may, however, [download a free 30 day trial version](http://www.jooq.org/download/) that works with SQL Server.

Note, there is also [a fix for jOOQ 3.2.1](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2801) (to be released soon), to give community edition users more information rather than just a stack trace.

See also: [jooq-3.2.0 and db2 database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19722416/521799)

Answer (score 2):

I want to share my working config for sql server 2012 and 2014 that both made it work after many attempts. 
I downloaded jooq3.7.2 enterprise edition to make it work.

Here is my sample config file "library.xml"

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.7.0.xsd">
  <!-- Configure the database connection here -->
  <jdbc>
    <driver>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver>
    <url>jdbc:sqlserver://testdelta1:1433;databaseName=NEO_DB</url>
    <user>LOB_ManilaUsers</user>
    <password>lobpassword3123</password>
  </jdbc>

  <generator>
    <!-- The default code generator. You can override this one, to generate your own code style.
         Supported generators:
         - org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator
         - org.jooq.util.ScalaGenerator
         Defaults to org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator -->
    <name>org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator</name>

    <database>
      <!-- The database type. The format here is:
           org.util.[database].[database]Database -->
      <!--<name>org.jooq.util.mysql.MySQLDatabase</name> -->
      <name>org.jooq.util.sqlserver.SQLServerDatabase</name>
      <!-- The database schema (or in the absence of schema support, in your RDBMS this
           can be the owner, user, database name) to be generated -->

      <!-- specify database name -->
      <inputSchema>dbo</inputSchema>

      <!-- All elements that are generated from your schema
           (A Java regular expression. Use the pipe to separate several expressions)
           Watch out for case-sensitivity. Depending on your database, this might be important! -->
      <includes>.*</includes>

      <!-- All elements that are excluded from your schema
           (A Java regular expression. Use the pipe to separate several expressions).
           Excludes match before includes -->
      <excludes></excludes>
    </database>

    <target>
      <!-- The destination package of your generated classes (within the destination directory) -->
      <packageName>com.neoapi.entity</packageName>

      <!-- The destination directory of your generated classes -->
      <directory>jooq_directory/src_generated</directory>
    </target>
  </generator>
</configuration>
```

Usually the default schema value is 'dbo'. At first, I entered 'NEO_DB' which did not work.

you can specify your desired  and

Free version or opensource jooq 3.7.2 does not contain the database name SQLServerDatabase. Enterprise edition(30 days trial) works. I'm not sure how the trial days start counting.

here is the sample log from my terminal:

```
> INFO: Generating table         : Tobservationrawdataobservations.java [input=tObservationRawDataObservations, output=tObservationRawDataObservations, pk=PK_ObservationRawDataObservations]
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:35 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info

INFO: Generating table         : UdvPublisheddata.java [input=udv_PublishedData, output=udv_PublishedData, pk=N/A]
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:40 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating table         : UdvPublishinghistory.java [input=udv_PublishingHistory, output=udv_PublishingHistory, pk=N/A]
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:40 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating table         : UdvScreamertanksystems.java [input=udv_ScreamerTankSystems, output=udv_ScreamerTankSystems, pk=N/A]
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:40 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating table         : UdvSiradwmconfig.java [input=udv_SiraDWMConfig, output=udv_SiraDWMConfig, pk=N/A]
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:40 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating table         : Vwauditlog.java [input=vwAuditLog, output=vwAuditLog, pk=N/A]
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:40 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating table         : Vwcompanysitetanksystem.java [input=vwCompanySiteTankSystem, output=vwCompanySiteTankSystem, pk=N/A]
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:40 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating table         : Vwdocketdeliveries.java [input=vwDocketDeliveries, output=vwDocketDeliveries, pk=N/A]
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:40 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Tables generated         : Total: 01:06
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:40 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating table references
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:40 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Table refs generated     : Total: 01:06, +17.847ms
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:40 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating Keys          
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:40 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Keys generated           : Total: 01:06, +49.833ms
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:40 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating table records 
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:40 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating record        : _Tmptsis_20151019Record.java
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:40 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating record        : DataRecord.java
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:40 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating record        : FuncgetchasedatatableRecord.java
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:40 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating record        : FuncgetcompliancestatisticspasstableRecord.java
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:40 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating record        : FuncgetcurrentfailsinctableRecord.java
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:40 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:40 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating record        : TcalibrationsRecord.java
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:40 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating record        : TcompaniesRecord.java
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:40 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating record        : TcompanyfilereadersRecord.java
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:40 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating record        : TcompanyrolecontactsRecord.java
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:40 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating record        : TcompanyrolepermissionsRecord.java
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:40 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating record        : TcompanyrolesRecord.java
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:40 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating record        : TcontactregionsRecord.java
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:40 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating record        : TcontactsRecord.java
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:40 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating record        : TcontactsitesRecord.java
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:40 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating record        : TcorrectiongroupRecord.java
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:40 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating record        : TcorrectiongroupsiteRecord.java
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:40 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating record        : TdomainusersRecord.java
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:40 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating record        : TfilereadersRecord.java
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:40 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating record        : TgradealiasesRecord.java
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:40 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating record        : TgradesRecord.java
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:40 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating record        : TimportedfilemessagesRecord.java
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:40 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating record        : TimportedfilesRecord.java
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:40 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating routine       : SpCreatediagram.java
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:43 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating routine       : SpDropdiagram.java
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:45 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating routine       : SpHelpdiagramdefinition.java
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:45 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating routine       : SpHelpdiagrams.java
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:46 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating routine       : SpRenamediagram.java
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:46 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Routines generated       : Total: 01:11, +5.132s
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:46 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Packages fetched         : 0 (0 included, 0 excluded)
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:46 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Removing excess files    
Feb 16, 2016 7:03:46 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: GENERATION FINISHED: dbo : Total: 01:11, +2.713ms
```